# 'sendto()' function won't send data to an application on another computer

Tags: sockets, posix, sendto

i wrote a client application in c using the posix sockets api on linux that sends information to a server, which then gets printed to the servers terminal window. If the server is on the same machine as the client and the client sends to the loopback or to its own IP address then all is good.  However, if the server is running on another machine, then sendto returns an "invalid argument" error.

Here is the code for the client application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "utils.h"   // for 'errexit()'


#define PEER_PORT 54321
#define BUFFSIZE 100
#define local_net_ip "192.168.0.10"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  int clientfd;

  clientfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
  if( clientfd == -1 )
    errexit( "socket()" );

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons( PEER_PORT );
  if( inet_pton( AF_INET, local_net_ip, (void *) &(servaddr.sin_addr) ) == -1 )
    errexit( "inet_pton()" );

  char addrStr[ INET_ADDRSTRLEN ];
  inet_ntop( servaddr.sin_family, &(servaddr.sin_addr), addrStr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN );
  printf("Server IPv4 addr:  [ %s ]\n", addrStr);

  char buff[ BUFFSIZE ];
  int writebytes;
  for( ;; ) {

    printf( "Enter text:  ");
    fgets( buff, BUFFSIZE, stdin );

    writebytes = sendto( clientfd, buff, BUFFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,         sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) );
    if( writebytes == -1 )
      errexit( "sendto()" );

  }


  exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );

}
```

I would greatly appreciate any information as to why the application won't send to another computer! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't think a firewall would cause sendto() to fail.  (It might cause the packet to never arrive at the receiving computer though)

Comment: Have you verified that you can ping 192.168.0.10 from that machine?  Perhaps your machine is not set up on the 192.168.0.* network?

Answer (score 1):

> clientfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );

You are creating a socket with protocol 0, e.g. IP. But later you use and IP:Port as a target. You probably wanted to use an UDP socket here (proto 17).